# Database: most efficient way to organize tables with nested has-many relationship

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, prisma

I need the following structure:
**Project** `--(has many)-->` **Topic** `--(has many)-->` **Article**

For a specific **Project** I want to query the **Articles** in a most efficient way.

What would be the best db architecture for this case? I'm considering following options:

1. Classic `one-to-many` relationship with `Topic.projectId` and `Article.topicId`. Here I'm concerned with having to query all Topics first.
2. **Project** `--(has many)-->` **Article** `--(has one)-->` **Topic** (via Article.projectId and Article.topicId). Also add `Topic.projectId` in case I need a list of Topics per Project. This way I'm querying directly Project's Articles (not through Topics as in option 1). My concern here is duplication of Topic's relation to Project: directly, and through Article.
3. Your option?

I'm using [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/), so it might have it's own best practices here.

Comment: If you know your `projectId = XXX`, then `SELECT * FROM Article A JOIN Topic T ON A.topicId = T.topicId WHERE T.projectId = XXX` will get what you want. It will retrieve only the `Topics` with `projectId = XXX`, not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your access pattern, this model makes sense:

```
model Project {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String
  topics   Topic[]
  articles Article[]
}

model Topic {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  project   Project?  @relation(fields: [projectId], references: [id])
  articles  Article[]
  projectId Int?
}

model Article {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  project   Project? @relation(fields: [projectId], references: [id])
  topic     Topic?   @relation(fields: [topicId], references: [id])
  projectId Int?
  topicId   Int?
}
```

With this setup, you would be able to fetch:

1. All articles corresponding to a given project and the respective topic
2. Articles for each topic
3. Topics present in a given project

Comment: Thanks a lot! What about the duplication of Topic's relation to Project: directly, and through Articles. Or is this common practice?

Comment: Yes. If querying without extra nesting is your main concern and that operation is frequent, then you can duplicate relations.